# Generate CSV file as a stream and send as Email attachment PHP /

Tags: php, csv, email

Here i'm getting csv file attachement,but not containing my original data.How do i solve this?

```
$csv_data =" Board Name : IT service,Board type : ,Started : 2015-02-17,Board Owner : Sathishkumar Natarajan,Week No : 25, Sprint Name : V1.2,Total No of Tickets : 0,Start date : Not Available,Days Left : 0 Ticket ID,Ticket Summary,Ticket Assigned to,Ticket Status,Total Working Hours,Estimated Hours 2242 , testvdvdf , Arun , Assigned , 0 , 1 "

$body ="Workdesk Board Report \r\n \r\n aaa.aaa.aai"; 
$to = 'aaa.s@aaa.com';                   
$subject = 'Wordesk Report';
$from = "aaa@aaa.com";   
$body = "\"Workdesk Report \r\n \r\n a.workdesk.ai\"";
// This will provide plenty adequate entropy
$multipartSep = '-----'.md5(time()).'-----';

// Arrays are much more readable
$headers = array(
                 "From: $from",
                 "Reply-To: $from",
                 "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$multipartSep\""
                );

// Open temp file pointer
if (!$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'w+')) return FALSE;

fputcsv($fp, array($csv_data));


// Place stream pointer at beginning
rewind($fp);

// Return the data
$att= stream_get_contents($fp);

// Make the attachment
$attachment = $att;

echo $attachment;

// Make the body of the message
$body = "--$multipartSep\r\n"
      . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed\r\n"
      . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n"
      . "\r\n"
      . "$body\r\n"
      . "--$multipartSep\r\n"
      . "Content-Type: text/csv\r\n"
      . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
      . "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"Website-Report-" . date("F-j-Y") . ".csv\"\r\n"
      . "\r\n"
      . "$attachment\r\n"
      . "--$multipartSep--";
if(@mail($to, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers))) {
    echo "Mail sent";
}else{
    echo "Mail not sent";
}
```

Comment: What does it contain then?

Comment: it's only contain csv file with an empty array

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Also please dont spam the tags you attach to your questions